# Batch using exact file path and names

Tags: batch-file, 7zip

I have a bunch of files stored on a server with the path like `\\Sname\Lev1\SubLev_A\....\FileName.pdf`. The exact paths and file names are stored in an SQL Server table so I can easily create a batch file to copy all the files. However, I would like to create a batch file to use 7Zip to zip the files into a single file.

Can you provide the 7zip scripting convention to accomplish that?
Example: 7z.bat might include something like

```
c:\7zip.exe \\Sname\Lev1\SubLev_A\FileName1.pdf Extract.zip
c:\7zip.exe \\Sname\Lev1\SubLev_A\FileName2.pdf Extract.zip 
...
c:\7zip.exe \\Sname\Lev99\SubLev_Z\FileName1000.pdf Extract.zip
```

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: 7z command `a` can add a file to an existing archive.

Comment: Removed tags from title; acronym capitalization; grammar; noise reduction. // https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/18966837